# Curve rope around corner

Tags: modeling

Is there a simple way to curve my rope along the red line?

Everything I find on curves seems quite complex, and I just make a mess of it.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using curves would probably be the best option for this, but as a simpler choice:

Create your rope shape out of single vertices:

[image: rope]

Then, just go to the modifiers tab and add a skin modifier.

If the mesh is too big, go into edit mode, select all the vertices, and use Ctrl+A to resize the skin.

If you want, you can add a subdivision surface modifier to make it smoother:

[image: final]

Answer (score 10):

Just borrow bits from your existing geometry. (If you model a lot, you learn to be lazy)

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> cut a loop round the middle of your spool, if there isn't one there already
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicate it and <kbd>P</kbd> separate the selection into a new object
- In Edit Mode, <kbd>S</kbd> scale it out about its median point a bit, <kbd>X</kbd>delete its bottom 2 edges
- <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>extrude the new end vertices down in Z
- .. and Header > Object Menu > convert to a curve.

[image]

You can bevel the curve in its Data tab > Geometry panel, and keep the bevel resolution down for a low-poly rope, or in the Header menu again, Edit Mode, all selected,Curve > Set Spline type to Bezier, and <kbd>V</kbd> set the control points to automatic to get a smooth rope... all sorts.